# Перетащить элемент

Tags: c#, delphi

Есть к примеру label1. Как сделать так, чтобы во время исполнения программы пользователь мог перетаскивать этот элемент? Пробую сделать при помощи MouseDown, MouseMove, MouseUp, но что-то не выходит. Можно расписать эти три события? Или как-то по другому сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Для Delphi:

1. По MouseDown вы присваиваете некоторой `boolean` переменной значение "истина", запоминаете текущие координаты мыши
2. В MouseMove вы проверяете значение из (1), если оно истина, рассчитываете смещение по `dX` и `dY` относительно полученных в (1). Единовременно меняя координаты вашего `label` (`label.top, label.left`) пользуясь рассчитанными параметрами
3. Переменной из (1) присваиваете значение "ложь".

Смещение можно рассчитывать по-разному, используя, например, некоторый коэффициент, который увеличивается по мере отдаления от исходной точки, тем самым увеличивая/уменьшая скорость перемещения.

Comment: А для c# так не получится.

Answer (score 1):

В событии `MouseDown` следует запомнить разность координат перетаскиваемого контрола и мыши.
В событии `MouseMove` пересчитывать координаты мыши в новые координаты контрола и задавать контролу свойство `Location`.
В событии `MouseUp` следует очищать запомненную разность координат.

Дополнительные условия.

1. В событии `MouseDown` следует проверять, что курсор мыши находится внутри контрола, который нужно переместить.
2. В событии `MouseMove` следует проверять, что разность координат задана - т.е., мышь нажата.

Если требуется перетаскивать разные контролы, то перетаскиваемый контрол должен запоминаться в поле класса формы вместе с разностью координат и вместе с ней сбрасываться.

Answer (score 0):

Как альтернатива - использовние popup menu,привязка к клавишам "стрелочки" либо назначение изменений свойств top и left на какие-либо клавиши.

Answer (score 0):

Если это не игра или подобное игре приложение, то можно сделать так (для Delphi):<br>
1. Компоненту для перетаскивания (например, Label1) присвоить параметру DragKind = dkDock;<br>
2. Параметру DragMode = dmAutomatic;<br>
3. Компоненту формы присвоить параметр DockSite = true.<br>
После этого этот компонент (Label1) можно будет перетаскивать, отстыковывать и пристыковывать к форме. Правда, пользователь может случайно его "уронить" и потерять, но тут нужно отслеживать такие случаи.<br>
Либо использовать события OnMouseDown, OnMouseMove и OnMouseUp с введением дополнительных переменных (например, булева dragging, x и y - предыдущие положения курсора).<br>
Вот для примера:<br>

```
lastpos:tpoint;
draging:boolean;
//MouseDown
begin
  lastpos:=mouse.CursorPos;
  draging:=true;
end;
//MouseUp
begin
  draging:=false;
end;
//MouseMove
begin
  if draging then
  begin
    top:=top-(lastpos.Y-mouse.CursorPos.Y);
    left:=left-(lastpos.X-mouse.CursorPos.X);
    lastpos:=mouse.CursorPos;
  end;
end;
```